# Need help with text animation within UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to implement a simple text animation in a custom UITableViewCell without having to go into editing mode which automatically brings up the delete button on the right. What I'm trying to accomplish is that when the label is updated by a button within the UITableviewcell, the text in the label is updated but with some smooth animation like sliding to the right since the updated text is prepended to the string. Any sample code would be great. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the text is in a UILabel, which is a subclass of UIView, and therefore can be animated using core animation:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];

[myTextLabel setText:newText];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```